# At what rate are the number of cores per CPU increasing?

Tags: parallel-processing

I'm designing a system that will be on-line in 2016 and run on commodity 1U or 2U server boxes.  I'd like to understand how parallel the software will need to be so I'd like to estimate the number of cores per physical machine.  I'm not interested in more exotic hardware like video game console processors, GPUs or DSPs.  I could extrapolate based on when chips where issued by Intel or AMD, but this historical information seems scarce.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a pretty long time. Out of curiousity, why can't you make it arbitrarily parallel?

Comment: You plan to grow the system over time with commodity hardware available as necessary? What's your plan for the data interconnects? What about migration off of old hardware as it becomes obsolete? Can you give us more detail about your task? Scaling can be really hard to get right...

Comment: @Paul It's in the initial proposal phase for funding.  The powers that be for this project would rather not have me discuss it so I've left it vague.

Comment: @Bobby GPUS and what not are not completely off the table, but the software we have now is single threaded.  We just break up the data by time or space and run multiple processes.  This strategy may not continue to scale in the future.  I don't need to get everything right at the moment I just need an estimate; something to think about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following charts from [Design for Manycore Systems](http://www.drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/showArticle.jhtml;jsessionid=0CW5VEYAYIUEVQE1GHOSKHWATMY32JVN?articleID=219200099):

[image]

[image]

Comment: this seems high. I have a machine that I estimate very high end at work and it has 4 cores, 8 threads. its your typical core i7. I'd like to know what kind of typical machine has 32 cores ?

Comment: And here we are in 2014, and nowhere near 128 cores per average commodity machine

Comment: @Siler Yep, shows how predictions aren't that helpful. I think that chart/article was saying we should be somewhere between 32-128 by 2014. Enthusiast-level Intel and AMD is still 4-8 cores. Progress has plateaued for the past several years.

Answer (score 2):

As the great computer scientist Yogi Berra said, "It's tough to make predictions, especially about the future.".  Given the relative recency of multicore systems, I think you're right to be wary of extrapolations.  Still, you need a number to aim for.

M. Spinelli's graphs are very valuable, and (I think) have the benefit of being based on real plans out to 2014.   Other than that, if you want a simple, easly calculatable and defensible number, I'd take as a starting point the number of cores in current (say) 2U systems at your price point (high range systems -- 24-32 cores at $15k; mid-range 12-16 cores at $8k, lower-end 8-12 core at $5k).  Then note that Moore's law suggests 8-16x as many transistors per unit silicon in 2016 as now, and that on current trends, these mainly go into more cores.  That suggests 64-512 cores per node depending on how much you're spending on each -- and these numbers are consistent with the graphs Matt Spinelli posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Cores per physical machine doesn't seem to be a particularly good metric, I think. We haven't really seen that number grow in particularly non-linear ways, and many-core hardware has been available COTS since the 90's (though it was relatively specialized at that point). If your task is really that parallel, quadrupling the number of cores shouldn't change it that much. We've always had the option of faster-but-fewer-cores, which should still be available to you in 6 years if you find that you don't scale well with the current number of cores.

If your application is really embarrassingly parallel, why are you unwilling to consider GPU solutions?

How quickly do you plan to rotate the hardware? Leave old machines till they die, or replace them proactively as they start to slow the cluster down? How many machines are we talking about? What kind of interconnect technology are you considering? For many cluster applications that is the limiting factor.

The drdobbs article above is not a bad analysis, but I think it misses the point just a tad. It's going to be a significant while before many mainstream apps can take advantage of really parallel general compute hardware (and many tasks simply can't be parallelized much), and when they do, they'll be using graphics cards and (to a less extent) soundcards as the specialized hardware they use to do it.

Comment: I fear that the embarrassing part is over and more attention ($) will need to be paid to making software parallelized.  Using GPUs, at this time, seems like it would require a major rewrite of the software we might reuse.  The memory bandwidth needed to feed the GPU seems like another factor to consider.  Perhaps that will be less of a concern when GPUs are integrated into the CPU socket.  In any case I would rather have a plan with fewer unknowns than more unknowns.